# How to validate that I don't receive both values defined in @JsonProperty and @JsonAlias?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I'm taking entity with child presented as numeric *child_entity_id*. But sometimes instead of *child_entity_id* I have to handle *child_entity_selector* json object instead. Which is sent for extracting the entity by some values from a database.

Parent entity has such annotations

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    long id;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EntityReferenceDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = EntityReferenceSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("child_entity_id")
    @JsonAlias("child_entity_selector")
    Child child;
```

For response json like

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "child_entity_id": 1,
    "child_entity_selector": {
        "child_name": "I am a child"
    },
}
```

An exception should be thrown because only "child_entity_id" or "child_entity_selector" have to be simultaneously in one json.

When I receive such json, it parses correctly, but my deserializer handles both of *child_entity_id* and *child_entity_selector* and the last one remains in the result.

Currently I'm trying to obtain both of source json and entity to check that json has not duplicated references covered by aliases.

I've set up a SimpleModule and the custom deserializer

```
@Component
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public SimpleModule simpleModule() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == Child.class)
                    return new ChildDeserializer(deserializer);
                return deserializer;
            }
        });
        return module;
    }
}
```

and deserializer

```
public class ChildDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Child> implements ResolvableDeserializer {
    private final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer;

    public ChildDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
        super(Child.class);
        this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Child deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Child modelExecution = (Child) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        // Can not correctly read raw json after parsing -- node becomes null now after deserialization above
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

        boolean duplication = node.has("child_entity_id") && node.has("child_entity_selector");
        if (duplication) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Duplicated!")
        } else {
            log("Not duplicated");
        }
            return child;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }

}
```

After the deserialization I can not access the JsonNode value. And vice versa after parsing JsonNode value can not obtain deserialized Child entity.

Expected behavior on

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "child_entity_id": 1,
}
```

and

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "child_entity_selector": {
        "child_name": "I am a child"
    },
}
```

is correctly parsed entity.

But on both of references

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "child_entity_id": 1,
    "child_entity_selector": {
        "child_name": "I am a child"
    },
}
```

an exception should be thrown.

Comment: `Only "child_entity_id" or "child_entity_id" is supposed to be presented in one json`
it is hard to understand what you mean

Comment: @BSeitkazin rephrased it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle it with a `@JsonCreator` in the Parent class

```
    @JsonCreator
    public Parent(@JsonProperty("child_entity_id") Child childFromId, @JsonProperty("child_entity_selector") Child childFromSelector) {
        if (childFromId != null && childFromSelector != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Duplicated!");
        }

        this.child = (childFromSelector == null) ? childFromId : childFromSelector;
    }
```

There is a `JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION` if you also need to check for duplicate fields:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "child_entity_id": 1,
    "child_entity_id": 2    
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with aliases

Comment: Yep, it works as desired on entity creation. However, it fails on update operation due to objectMapper.readerForUpdating with exception "PatchUpdateException details: No fallback setter/field defined for creator property 'child_entity_ref' (through reference chain: Parent[\"child_entity_ref\"])"

Comment: I've not used update, sounds like the `@JsonAlias` is being ignored. You could try 2 setters that both set child field, one marked with `@JsonProperty("child_entity_id")` the other with `@JsonProperty("child_entity_selector")`. Sounds a bit scruffy though, and it won't detect duplicates.

Comment: The ideal approach will be to modify json on deserialization, when I have both raw json and entity type. From entity class I could extract fileds with the annotations and validate|modify entity